# Bootstrap scrollspy not working absolutely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a website and the bootstrap scrollspy not working at all. I don't know what I did wrong, I followed the bootstrap FAQ.

Here's my code:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/parallax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <meta name="description" content="Ez itt a leírása a weboldalnak.">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav" data-offset="50">
    <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo_small.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Our team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Career</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

UPDATE:
***SOLVED***
I accidentally added a scrollspy snippet in main.js before I tried to add scrollspy with data attributes. *FACEPALM*

Comment: UPDATE:
*SOLVED*
I accidentally added a scrollspy snippet in main.js before I tried to add scrollspy with data attributes. *FACEPALM*